# Generating a String from CLLocationDegrees, e.g. in NSLog or StringWithFormat

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nslog

**Hello Stacked-Experts!**

My question: How to generate a string from a CLLocationDegrees value?

Failed attempts:

```
1. NSLog(@"Value: %f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude); //Tried with all NSLog specifiers.
2. NSNumber *tmp = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
3. NSString *tmp = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
```

When I look in the definition for the CLLocationDegrees it clearly states that this is a double:

```
typedef double CLLocationDegrees;
```

What am I missing here? This is making me go crazy... Please help to save my mind!

Thanks in advance and best regards.
//Abeansits

Answer (score 35, accepted):

These are correct:

```
NSLog(@"Value: %f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude); //Tried with all NSLog specifiers.
NSNumber *tmp = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
```

This is wrong, because coordinate.latitude isn't an object as nsstring might expect.

```
NSString *tmp = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
```

If you want an NSString:

```
myString = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude] stringValue];
```

or

```
NSString *tmp = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
```

Marco

Comment: Thank you Marco! This is so true.
My error actually resided in a faulty memory allocation. =(
Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift version:**

Latitude to String:

```
var latitudeText = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
```

or

```
let latitudeText = String(format: "%f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
```

Answer (score 0):

Obj-C format

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
```

Swift format

```
String(format: "%f", coordinate.latitude)
```